# 2 Less Parameter with one being null by default

Tags: less, png

Hey I have 2 sets of icon styles. Black and White

```
 settings-icon-white.png  or  settings-icon.png
```

Now I am using a Less mixin which takes a text parameter:

```
 //The mixin
.icon-finder(@url){ 
  background-image: url("../images/icons/backend/@{url}-icon.png");
  background-size: cover;
}

//generated class:login-icon.png
.icon-login{
  .icon-finder(login);
}
```

Now the challenge is that I want to also have an option to select a white icon if the parameter gets passed a `white`. Is there a way to have a default null parameter, but can be used if need be?

So for example:

```
.icon-finder(@url,@white){
   background-image: url("../images/icons/backend/@{url}-icon@{white}.png");
   background-position: center center;
}
```

But I don't want white the whole time, so can this be null? `@white = ""` I did see this `@_` being [used before](http://www.sitepoint.com/a-comprehensive-introduction-to-less-mixins/) - is that right?

So the code would be like:

```
.icon-admin{
   .icon-finder(admin);
}
.icon-admin-white{
   .icon-finder(admin,white);
}
```

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do I put `@white = '' ` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set a default value to a mixin argument by just specifying it in the mixin declaration like in the below code block. The `@white: ''` part means that the mixin will take the value for `@white` as an empty string when no value is provided in the call.

```
.icon-finder(@url,@white: ''){
   background-image: url("../images/icons/backend/@{url}-icon@{white}.png");
   background-position: center center;
}
.icon-admin{
   .icon-finder(admin);
}
.icon-admin-white{
   .icon-finder(admin,white);
}
```

There is no need to use the `@_` syntax that is mentioned in the link.

---

Note that if you are writing something like a mixin library and want to restrict the values for the second parameter to white or nothing (the above mixin allows you to send any value for second param), then you could use one of the following options also:

**Option 1:** Two separate mixins, one with a hard-coded `white` value (note that it is not a variable) and another with only one parameter. This way if the user tries to pass any other value it will be rejected.

```
.icon-finder(@url,white) {
   background-image: url("../images/icons/backend/@{url}-iconwhite.png");
   background-position: center center;
}
.icon-finder(@url){
   background-image: url("../images/icons/backend/@{url}-icon.png");
   background-position: center center;
}
.icon-admin{
   .icon-finder(admin);
}
.icon-admin-white{
   .icon-finder(admin,white);
}
```

**Option 2:** Using guards and checking if the value is white or not. If it is then use the white background image, else use the default.

```
.icon-finder(@url,@white: '') {
  & when (@white = white){
   background-image: url("../images/icons/backend/@{url}-iconwhite.png");
   background-position: center center;
  }
  & when not (@white = white){
   background-image: url("../images/icons/backend/@{url}-icon.png");
   background-position: center center;
  }
}
.icon-admin{
   .icon-finder(admin);
}
.icon-admin-white{
   .icon-finder(admin,white);
}
```

The advantage of the first option is that if any value other than white is given, the compiler would throw an error and alert the user that a wrong value is provided whereas the second one will silently switch to the default.

Comment: Ah yeah thank you! I figured it out! This is the right answer! Thanks!

Comment: Dont have the reputation.